# how to add getopt options in a bash script

Tags: python, bash, bioinformatics

I have written a bash script that consists of multiple Unix commands and Python scripts. The goal is to make a pipeline for detecting long non coding RNA from a certain input. Ultimately I would like to turn this into an 'app' and host it on some bioinformatics website. One problem I am facing is using `getopt` tools in bash. I couldn't find a good tutorial that I understand clearly. In addition any other comments related to the code is appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "-h" ]
then
    echo "Usage: sh $0 cuffcompare_output reference_genome blast_file"
    exit
else
wget https://github.com/TransDecoder/TransDecoder/archive/2.0.1.tar.gz && tar xvf 2.0.1 && rm -r 2.0.1
makeblastdb -in $3 -dbtype nucl -out $3.blast.out
grep '"u"' $1 | \
gffread -w transcripts_u.fa -g $2 - && \
python2.7 get_gene_length_filter.py transcripts_u.fa transcripts_u_filter.fa && \
TransDecoder-2.0.1/TransDecoder.LongOrfs -t transcripts_u_filter.fa
sed 's/ .*//' transcripts_u_filter.fa | grep ">" | sed 's/>//' > transcripts_u_filter.fa.genes
cd transcripts_u_filter.fa.transdecoder_dir
sed 's/|.*//' longest_orfs.cds | grep ">" | sed 's/>//' | uniq > longest_orfs.cds.genes
grep -v -f longest_orfs.cds.genes ../transcripts_u_filter.fa.genes > longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes
sed 's/^/>/' longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes > temp && mv temp longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes
python ../extract_sequences.py longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes ../transcripts_u_filter.fa longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa
blastn -query longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa -db ../$3.blast.out -out longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out -outfmt 6
python ../filter_sequences.py longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out.filtered
grep -v -f longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa.blast.out.filtered longest_orfs.cds.genes.not.genes.fa > lincRNA_final.fa
fi
```

Here is how I run it:

```
sh test.sh cuffcompare_out_annot_no_annot.combined.gtf /mydata/db/Brapa_sequence_v1.2.fa TE_RNA_transcripts.fa
```

Comment: Use bash functions, like: `fetch_data | length_filter | find_longest | do_something | and_other_thing` - and the particular functions should contain the actual code such `fetch_data() { wget ....; }` and so on. It is more readable and manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted the call to be :

```
test -c cuffcompare_output -r reference_genome -b blast_file
```

You would have something like :

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":b:c:hr:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    b)
      blastfile=$OPTARG
      ;;
    c)
      comparefilefile=$OPTARG
      ;;
    h)
      echo "USAGE : test -c cuffcompare_output -r reference_genome -b blast_file"
      ;;
    r)
      referencegenome=$OPTARG
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

In the string ":b:c:hr:",
- the first ":" tells getopts that we'll handle any errors,
- subsequent letters are the allowable flags.  If the letter is followed by a ':', then getopts will expect that flag to take an argument, and supply that argument as $OPTARG

Comment: Then how do you substitute the flags in the actual code. For example when i include your code and follow that with a test code - `makeblastdb -in blastfile -dbtype nucl -out blastfile.blast.out` i am getting error `Unable to open input blast_file`

Comment: use the $ prefix to use the variable :  makeblastdb -in $blastfile .......    By the way, When you say you run by "sh test.sh ...", you don't need the first "sh" - you should be able to run test.sh directly :)

Comment: Glad to help :).   Btw, if you're new to shell scripting, it won't be long before you'll need to know the effects of the different quote characters (single, double, etc). Check out http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch08_14.html.  Ps. Appreciate if you select the answer, thanks :)

Comment: I have a question. When i run the name of the script without any options and then hit enter, i am not getting error message and whatever downstream gets processed. How do i make sure that if i enter without any options, i should get an error message saying what all are required?

Comment: getopts does not provide an option for saying "this flag must be present", so typically you'd only want to use this for arguments that are optional (and/or would have default values);  I prefer mandatory arguments to be specified as arguments after the getopts flagged arguments - again typically you'd follow the 'while' loop by a "shift $((OPTIND-1))", so you can start addressing those arguments as $1, etc.  To flag an error if any getopts flags have not been specified, you'd have to use an 'if' statement after the getopts 'while' loop.